# Opinion on native base List component

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to know that whether the `<List>` component being provided by native-base
styling library can be an alternative for `<ListView>` component.
I know that the the traditional listview by react-native is performance efficient
so is the List component of native base also performance efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check NativeBase Docs https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref

It says, List is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the info is there anyother List by nativebase which can be used for the purpose of dynamic  rendering.

Answer (score 0):

NativeBases `List` component is actually just a wrapper over React Native's `ListView` with some extra goodies included, so efficiency in terms of cell reuse, etc should be good.

See the [source for `List`](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/769913788ef412d1c0f22547760089f43ad03943/src/basic/List.js).